# Mongoose: Calculate number of distinct field values in array returned as result of $lookup aggregation step

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with a problem of how to get the number of distinct field values in array returned as result of `$lookup` aggregation step in MongoDB using Mongoose. By the number of distinct field values I mean the number of rows with unique value on certain field.

Parent document has this structure:
`{ _id: 678, name: "abc" }`

Child document has this structure:
`{ _id: 1009, fieldA: 123, x: { id: 678, name: "abc" } }`

`$lookup` step is defined as follow:

```
{
 from "children",
 localField: "_id"
 foreignField: "x.id"
 as: "xyz"
}
```

Let's assume that I get this array as a result of `$lookup` aggregation step for a parent with `_id` equal to: **678**

```
xyz: [ 
{ _id: 1009, fieldA: 123, x: { id: 678, name: "abc" } }, 
{ _id: 1010, fieldA: 3435, x: { id: 678, name: "abc" } }, 
{ _id: 1011, fieldA: 123, x: { id: 678, name: "abc" } } 
]
```

I want to know how many distinct `fieldA` values are in this array. *In this example it would be 2*.

Of coure the step should be in aggregation flow, ater `$lookup` step and before (inside?) `$project` step. As a side note I must to add that I also need total number of elements in array `xyz` as another value (`$size` operator in `$project` step).

Comment: What have you actually tried?. You might find people more receptive to helping if you actually demonstrated that you have made some effort to solve this by inlcluding your attempts and showing what does not work for you and what you expected. Also, *"Of coure the step should be in aggregation flow, ater `$lookup`..."*. As a big hint, that statement is not actually optimal. If you only want singular "total" and "distinct" values, then doing that *after* is the worst performing case. There is a "inside" with modern MongoDB releases.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside"? As far as I understand, $lookup always returns an array of values so returning just number of distinct values and total number of fields is not possible using this operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given what you are saying, then you would basically have some data like this:

**parents**

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "xyz": ["abc", "abd", "abe", "abf"]
}
```

**children**

```
{ "_id": "abc", "fieldA": 123 },
{ "_id": "abd", "fieldA": 34 },
{ "_id": "abe", "fieldA": 123 },
{ "_id": "abf", "fieldA": 54 }
```

> **N.B.** If you actually defined the parent reference within the child instead of an array of child references in the parent, then there is a listing example at the bottom. The same principles generally apply in either case however.

Where your current [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) that produces a result like that in the question would be something like this:

```
{ "$lookup": {
  "from": "children",
  "localField": "xyz",
  "foreignField": "_id"
  "as": "xyz"
}}
```

### Best Approach

Now you *could* do other operations on the array returned in order to actually return the total count and distinct counts, but there is a better way with any modern MongoDB release which you *should* be using. Namely there is a more expressive form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which allows a `pipeline` to be specified to act on the resulting children:

```
Parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "let": { "ids": "$xyz" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$ids" ] }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$fieldA",
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "distinct": { "$sum": 1 },
        "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "xyz"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
    "distinctCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.distinct" },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.total" }
  }}
])
```

The whole point there being that you don't actually *need* all the array results to be returned from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), so instead of working with the returned array of all matching children you just *reduce* that content from *within* the `pipeline` expression of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

In order to get a total count and a *distinct* count for the inner content, after the initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) conditions which specify the "join" and what matches to return, you would then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the *"distinct"* value as the key and maintain a *"count"* of the elements found in total. The second [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) uses a `null` value for the key since the only thing you want now is the *count* of the *distinct keys* already returned, and of course return the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of the existing total of counted elements.

The result being of course:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "distinctCount": 3,
  "totalCount": 4
}
```

And since we are using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) this would be in *addition* to all other fields present in the **parent** document with the exception of `xyz` which we explicitly removed via the `$$REMOVE` operator.

You might also note the usage of [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in that last stage. The actual result of our [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) *pipeline* is of course a **single document**, but it is as *always* within an *array*, since that is what the output of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) *always* is. In this case it's just a very simple way ( being the shortest syntax ) to just extract those values from the array as individual fields in the parent document instead.

### Alternate

The alternate approach is of course to just work with the returned array, and all this really needs is essentially *any* of the appropriate ["set operators"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-expression-operators) and the `$size` operator:

```
Parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "localField": "xyz",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "xyz"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
    "distinctCount": { "$size": { "$setUnion": [ [], "$xyz.fieldA" ] }},
    "totalCount": { "$size": "$xyz" }
  }}
])
```

Here we use [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) basically providing arguments of an empty array `[]` and the array of `fieldA` values. Since this would return a "set" that is the combination of both arguments, the one thing that defines a "set" is that the values can appear only **once** and are thus ***distinct**. This is a quick way of obtaining only the *distinct* values and then of course each "array" ( or "set" ) is simply measured by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) for their respective counts.

So it *"looks simple"* but the problem is that it's not really efficient, and mostly because we spent operational time returning those array values from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and then we basically discarded the result. This is generally why the former approach is preferred since it will actually *reduce* the result *before* it is ever returned as an array. So "less work" overall.

If on the other hand you actually want to keep the array returned from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result then the *latter* case would be of course more desirable

---

### Example listing

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);


const parentSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  xyz: [{ type: String, ref: 'Child' }]
},{ _id: false });

parentSchema.index({ "xyz": 1 });

const childSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  fieldA: Number
},{ _id: false });

const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
const Child = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);


const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, options);

    // Clean data for demonstration
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.deleteMany())
    );


    // Insert some data
    await Parent.create({ "_id": 1, "xyz": ["abc", "abd", "abe", "abf"] });
    await Child.insertMany([
     { "_id": "abc", "fieldA": 123 },
     { "_id": "abd", "fieldA": 34 },
     { "_id": "abe", "fieldA": 123 },
     { "_id": "abf", "fieldA": 54 }
    ]);


    let result1 = await Parent.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Child.collection.name,
        "let": { "ids": "$xyz" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$ids" ] }
          }},
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$fieldA",
            "total": { "$sum": 1 }
          }},
          { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "distinct": { "$sum": 1 },
            "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
          }}
        ],
        "as": "xyz"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
        "distinctCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.distinct" },
        "totalCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.total" }

      }}
    ]);

    log({ result1 });

    let result2 = await Parent.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Child.collection.name,
        "localField": "xyz",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "xyz"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
        "distinctCount": { "$size": { "$setUnion": [ [], "$xyz.fieldA" ] } },
        "totalCount": { "$size": "$xyz" }
      }}
    ]);

    log({ result2 })

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: parents.createIndex({ xyz: 1 }, { background: true })
Mongoose: parents.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: children.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: parents.insertOne({ xyz: [ 'abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf' ], _id: 1, __v: 0 }, { session: null })
Mongoose: children.insertMany([ { _id: 'abc', fieldA: 123, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abd', fieldA: 34, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abe', fieldA: 123, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abf', fieldA: 54, __v: 0 }], {})
Mongoose: parents.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'children', let: { ids: '$xyz' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$ids' ] } } }, { '$group': { _id: '$fieldA', total: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$group': { _id: null, distinct: { '$sum': 1 }, total: { '$sum': '$total' } } } ], as: 'xyz' } }, { '$addFields': { xyz: '$$REMOVE', distinctCount: { '$sum': '$xyz.distinct' }, totalCount: { '$sum': '$xyz.total' } } }], {})
{
  "result1": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "distinctCount": 3,
      "totalCount": 4
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: parents.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'children', localField: 'xyz', foreignField: '_id', as: 'xyz' } }, { '$addFields': { xyz: '$$REMOVE', distinctCount: { '$size': { '$setUnion': [ [], '$xyz.fieldA' ] } }, totalCount: { '$size': '$xyz' } } }], {})
{
  "result2": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "distinctCount": 3,
      "totalCount": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

### Example without child array in parent

Shows defining a schema without an array of values in the parent and instead defining the parent reference within all children:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);


const parentSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
},{ _id: false });

parentSchema.virtual("xyz", {
  ref: 'Child',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'parent',
  justOne: false
});

const childSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  parent: Number,
  fieldA: Number
},{ _id: false });

childSchema.index({ "parent": 1 });


const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
const Child = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);


const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, options);

    // Clean data for demonstration
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.deleteMany())
    );


    // Insert some data
    await Parent.create({ "_id": 1 });
    await Child.insertMany([
     { "_id": "abc", "fieldA": 123 },
     { "_id": "abd", "fieldA": 34 },
     { "_id": "abe", "fieldA": 123 },
     { "_id": "abf", "fieldA": 54 }
    ].map(e => ({ ...e, "parent": 1 })));


    let result1 = await Parent.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Child.collection.name,
        "let": { "parent": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$parent", "$$parent" ] }
          }},
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$fieldA",
            "total": { "$sum": 1 }
          }},
          { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "distinct": { "$sum": 1 },
            "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
          }}
        ],
        "as": "xyz"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
        "distinctCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.distinct" },
        "totalCount": { "$sum": "$xyz.total" }

      }}
    ]);

    log({ result1 });

    let result2 = await Parent.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Child.collection.name,
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "parent",
        "as": "xyz"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "xyz": "$$REMOVE",
        "distinctCount": { "$size": { "$setUnion": [ [], "$xyz.fieldA" ] } },
        "totalCount": { "$size": "$xyz" }
      }}
    ]);

    log({ result2 })

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: children.createIndex({ parent: 1 }, { background: true })
Mongoose: parents.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: children.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: parents.insertOne({ _id: 1, __v: 0 }, { session: null })
Mongoose: children.insertMany([ { _id: 'abc', fieldA: 123, parent: 1, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abd', fieldA: 34, parent: 1, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abe', fieldA: 123, parent: 1, __v: 0 }, { _id: 'abf', fieldA: 54, parent: 1, __v: 0 }], {})
Mongoose: parents.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'children', let: { parent: '$_id' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$parent', '$$parent' ] } } }, { '$group': { _id: '$fieldA', total: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$group': { _id: null, distinct: { '$sum': 1 }, total: { '$sum': '$total' } } } ], as: 'xyz' } }, { '$addFields': { xyz: '$$REMOVE', distinctCount: { '$sum': '$xyz.distinct' }, totalCount: { '$sum': '$xyz.total' } } }], {})
{
  "result1": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "distinctCount": 3,
      "totalCount": 4
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: parents.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'children', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'parent', as: 'xyz' } }, { '$addFields': { xyz: '$$REMOVE', distinctCount: { '$size': { '$setUnion': [ [], '$xyz.fieldA' ] } }, totalCount: { '$size': '$xyz' } } }], {})
{
  "result2": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "__v": 0,
      "distinctCount": 3,
      "totalCount": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following first approach suggested by @Neil Lunn. Due to a fact that my schemas of parent and child are different from those assumed by @Neil Lunn I post my own answer whitch solves my particular problem:

```
Parent.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "children",
          let: { id: "$_id" },
          pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$x.id", "$$id"] } } },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "$fieldA",
                count: { $sum: 1 }
              }
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                fieldA: { $sum: 1 },
                count: { $sum: "$count" }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "children"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
           total: { $sum: "$children.count" },
           distinct: { $sum: "$children.fieldA" }
        }
      }
    ]);
```